# Menu not working after configure tailwindcss

Tags: vuejs2, tailwind-css, laravel-7

I'm using laravel and I installed and configured tailwind but now the bootstrap menu is not displaying.
If I remove the tailwind configuration the menu works.
I try differents type of configuration none of them works
what's not allowing display the menu

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
 
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js')]
    })
    .sass('resources/sass/index.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/landing/style.scss', 'public/css/landing')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sourceMaps().vue();

mix.version();
```

menu.blade.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @auth
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">
            {{-- {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel55454') }} --}}
            <img src="{{ asset('/img/landing/dilogo_img.svg') }}" alt="">
        </a>
        @endauth
        @guest
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('home') }}">
            {{-- {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel5545') }} --}}
            <img src="{{ asset('/img/landing/dilogo_img.svg') }}" alt="">
        </a>
        @endguest

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">

        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

            </ul>

            <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <!-- Authentication Links -->
                @guest
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                    </li>
                    @if (Route::has('register'))
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                        </li>
    
...
...
```

app.scss

```
// Tailwind
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 3):

I had tailwind installed then installed bootstrap to create a reactive menu. Found I could not get the menu to work correctly without disabling the tailwind visibility ""core Plugin".

you do this by adding :

```
corePlugins: {
    visibility: false,
}
```

to your tailwind.config.js

Comment: Also, if you inspect your bootstrap menu, you can see that it is referencing a class called .collapse. This is usually only defined by bootstrap. However, tailwind it seems also has a class called .collapse. which it looks like is on line 1141 of tailwindcss v3.4.1 css file. The code above disables this tailwind class so the menu works correctly.